How do I install mysql-xdevapi on arch?
$ sudo pecl install mysql_xdevapi
I'm getting this error:
In file included from /usr/include/php/main/php.h:257,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/mysql_xdevapi/php_api.h:31,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/mysql_xdevapi/util/strings.h:21,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/mysql_xdevapi/util/exceptions.h:21,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/mysql_xdevapi/xmysqlnd/xmysqlnd_compression.cc:24:
/usr/include/boost/assert/source_location.hpp: In member function ‘std::string boost::source_location::to_string() const’:
/usr/include/php/main/snprintf.h:99:18: error: ‘ap_php_snprintf’ is not a member of ‘std’; did you mean ‘ap_php_snprintf’?
   99 | #define snprintf ap_php_snprintf
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/php/main/snprintf.h:74:12: note: ‘ap_php_snprintf’ declared here
   74 | PHPAPI int ap_php_snprintf(char *, size_t, const char *, ...) ZEND_ATTRIBUTE_FORMAT(printf, 3, 4);
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/php/main/snprintf.h:99:18: error: ‘ap_php_snprintf’ is not a member of ‘std’; did you mean ‘ap_php_snprintf’?
   99 | #define snprintf ap_php_snprintf
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/php/main/snprintf.h:74:12: note: ‘ap_php_snprintf’ declared here
   74 | PHPAPI int ap_php_snprintf(char *, size_t, const char *, ...) ZEND_ATTRIBUTE_FORMAT(printf, 3, 4);
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [Makefile:479: xmysqlnd/xmysqlnd_compression.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed

